# VBA: error when using .ChartData.Workbook.Close-command

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm using the below code to copy data from an (external) excel-file which (I opened before)to a datasheet of a graph in PowerPoint.
I've worked with this code several times and it always worked fine.

But for about a week now it suddenly stopped working at the point when the datasheet of the graph (where I paste in the data from the external excel-file) should be closed with

> .ChartData.Workbook.Close

I get this error message now: *Runtime error '1004': Method 'Close' of object '_Workbook' failed*
I tested it with another laptop and I'm afraid now that it doesn't work anymore due to an update.

Does anybody have an idea why it stops at this point or have an idea how to solve the problem that the datasheet of the graph cannot be closed?

Thanks in advance!!

```
chartno= 2

            With pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(chartno).Shapes("graph").Chart
                With .ChartData
                    .Activate
                    With .Workbook.Worksheets(1)


                            For row= 4 To 17
                                .Cells(row- 2, 2) = file_rawdata.Sheets(1).Cells(row, 2).Value
                            Next row
                            For row= 4 To 17
                                .Cells(row- 2, 3) = file_rawdata.Sheets(1).Cells(row, 2 + 1).Value
                            Next row                                             


                    End With
                End With
                .ChartData.Workbook.Close
            End With
```

Comment: I faced the same issue. Did you figuered out the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But I'm still trying to find a solution. Which Office version are you using?

Comment: 16.0.12624.20424 — version of my Power Point

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (in C#).

Replacing...

```
Workbook.Close()
```

...with...

```
Workbook.Application.Quit()
```

...solved it in my case!